# It shows, Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: django

When I submit then shows this error.

***views.py:***

```
class userINFOupdate(View):
    def get(self,request):  
        userid = request.GET.get("user_up_id")
        username = request.GET.get('user_up_username')
        email = request.GET.get('user_up_email')
        phone = request.GET.get('user_up_phoneNumber') 
        address = request.GET.get('user_up_address')

        obj = AJAXCRUD.objects.get(id=userid)
        print(userid)
```

***template:***

```
<input type="text" hidden name="user_up_id" id="user_hid_id" class="user_hidden_id">
```

***urls.py:***

```
path('userINFOupdate/', views.userINFOupdate.as_view(), name="userINFOupdate")
```

Comment: When going the url, you need to pass `user_up_id` in url querystring

Comment: You did not specify a `value="..."`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I do it?

Comment: You add `value="{{ user_up_id }}"` to the input tag in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting **user_up_id** as a string. You have to first typecast the variable into an int in views.py.

```
userid = int(request.GET.get("user_up_id"))
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If your objects have an integer `id` field, you can still retrieve it with `MyModel.objects.get(id='123')`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by doing the following:

1. Deleted all migration files except 0001_initial.py
2. Created a new migration with => python manage.py makemigrations
3. Committed the new migration to db => python manage.py migrate.

In my case, the error existed because the app was running an old migration which was causing this error.
I hope it works for you too